# Android ignoring :before pseudo padding and margin

Tags: android, html, css, pseudo-element

I'm using the :before pseudo class to add an icon to a hyperlink by giving it specific font-family and content properties. In addition, the :before selector has a padding-right (or margin-right) so that the icon doesn't sit flush against the text. In all browsers except for my S4 cell phone, the padding-right works. I cannot find any documentation or support for getting the S4 to render the icon spacing properly.

Has anyone else ran into this and if so, did you obtain a fix?

```
<a class="icon-star"> This is a start icon </a>
```